# Why is my img incorrectly sized within my HTML/CSS Table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a table within my `div sectionPhotographer` to properly space my content. I have styled the table so that each `td` fills 50% of the `div sectionPhotographer`. I would like to place an img in one of the cells, however, the img is not sizing the way I would like it to.

```css
.sectionPhotographer {
  height: 90%;
  background: #00aeef;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sectionPhotographer table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sectionPhotographer td {
  width: 50%;
}

.sectionPhotographer img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionPhotographer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/">
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>Turn your pictures into profits</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I set the height of `img` to 100%, I would expect it to fill the `td` it's in. However, it sizes it way too large. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: no need to put both width and max-width ... width:100% will force it to take the whole place and max-widh will force it to not overflow but it can be less than 100% if the image is small for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add width:100% like this:

```css
.sectionPhotographer {
  height: 90%;
  background: #00aeef;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sectionPhotographer table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sectionPhotographer td {
  width: 50%;
}

.sectionPhotographer img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionPhotographer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/">
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>Turn your pictures into profits</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```